# does the hilbert space construction of random variables allow for infinite variance?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, random-variables

I am reading a book (Hilbert Space Methods in Probability and Statistical Inference by Small) which says that random variables can be viewed as functions in the hilbert space $L^2$ with the inner product defined as expectation $\left<X,Y\right> = E\left(XY\right)$.  However, inner products must be finite as far as I know. Does this mean that the hilbert space view of random variables is unable to handle cauchy random variables and others with non-finite moments?

(this question moved from stats.stackexchange)

Comment: Yes to your body question, no to your title question.